# Fatal error in front page

Tags: fatal-error

my website shows below error in front page

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Xsitemap_Helper_Data' not found in /home/***/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

any idea how to solve this error?

Thank You

Comment: have you created system.xml ?

Comment: in Xsitemap/etc/system.xml what do use in module="" under xml tag ?

Comment: Have you defined the helpers node in your Xsitemap module's config xml, and does the helper actually exist? Maybe you mistakenly call xsitemap as helper, where you mean sitemap? As in: `Mage::helper('xsitemap')->__(string)` instead of `Mage::helper('sitemap')->__(string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue previously, So i have applied below fixes and it's working properly.
I have added helper note on `config.xml` file and delete cache folder.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml

<global>
         <helpers>
             <catalogrule>
                 <class>Mage_Catalog_Helper</class>
             </catalogrule>
         </helpers> 
</global>
```

You need to create a helper class and add above node on module config file.